# Is it expected that if you manually change a participant status from Partially Paid to something else, it waives the remaining fees?

Tags: civievent

If you have a participant who has only partially paid, civi sets the status to Partially Paid. If you try to change it manually to something else because you have a set of statuses you prefer to use, then civi pops up a warning box, but it doesn't tell what you the consequences are. What it does is waive the remaining fees by changing the original cost of the event for the participant.

Is this expected?

I can't just change the label on Partially Paid, because there is more than one status the participant could be in during their partially paid phase.

Steps:

1. Events - Register Participant.
2. Pick stuff.
3. In the payment section, change the amount paid to less than the total.
4. Civi will automatically adjust the status to partially paid as soon as you click outside the amount field.
5. Change the status to something else (in my case a custom status but it doesn't matter it's the same result - pick Attended).
6. Save. You get the popup. Click ok.
7. Now look at the participant record.

Comment: How are you causing this exactly? I'm not seeing any change to the fees, payments or contribution when changing from Partially Paid to Registered.

Comment: I'll update the question.

Comment: I see though if you leave it at partially paid and then go back and edit the participant record later and change the status, it doesn't update any monies. So at the very least seems inconsistent, or a magic feature.

Comment: Oh, that's fun. I'd say bug.